# Export as PDF Using PHP COM

Tags: php, excel, pdf, com

I want to convert an Excel file to PDF.
Here is my code:

```
function excel() {
  $excel = new COM("Excel.Application") or die ("ERROR: Unable to instantaniate COM!\r\n");

  $file = base_url('archieve/ADAF - 2018000007.xlsx');

  $Workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Open($file) or die("ERROR: Unable to open " . $file . "!\r\n");
  $Worksheet = $Workbook->Worksheets(1);

  echo 'file loaded';

  $xlTypePDF = 0;
  $xlQualityStandard = 0;

  try {
      $Worksheet->ExportAsFixedFormat($xlTypePDF, base_url('archieve/ADAF test.pdf'), $xlQualityStandard);

  } catch(com_exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
      exit;
  }

  echo 'file convert';

  $excel = NULL;

  unset($excel);
}
```

When I run the function, the server is still loading and reaches timeout. The code is in a different server.

Is my code wrong? Since I have tested in local PC and it works.

I tried to run the COM using Python and it worked fine. Turns out there is a problem in PHP when export as pdf. I still have the issue. Any suggestions?